# 2 class html on 1 execution in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, logic

Hello im having problem in carousel, i can execute 2 of them in jquery but the slide wont move, can anyone help me?
and in mobile view it work for slide.
also can i use array for jquery selector id?

This is my javascript

```js
    var carouselWidth = $(".card-inner, .card2")[0].scrollWidth;
    var cardWidth = $(".card-item, .item2").width();
    var scrollPosition = 0;
    var multipleCardCarousel = document.querySelectorAll(
      "#carouselExampleControls, #carouselExampleControls2"
    );
    if($('li.kategori').hasClass('active')){
      var scrollPosition = 0;
    }
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
      //rest of the code
      var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(multipleCardCarousel, {
        interval: false
      });
    } else {
      $(multipleCardCarousel).addClass("slide");
    }
    $(".carousel-nx, .carousel-nx2").eaech("click", function () {
      if (scrollPosition < (carouselWidth - cardWidth * 6)) { //check if you can go any further
        console.log('next');
        scrollPosition += cardWidth;  //update scroll 
        $(".card-inner, .card2").animate({ scrollLeft: scrollPosition },600); //scroll left
      }
    });
    $(".carousel-pv, .carousel-pv2").eaech("click", function () {
      if (scrollPosition > 0) {
        console.log('prev');
        scrollPosition -= cardWidth;
        $(".card-inner, .card2").animate(
          { scrollLeft: scrollPosition },
          600
        );
      }
    });
```

And this is my html

```html
        <!---Slide Start Card--->
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide carouselss" data-bs-ride="carousel">
           <!--START ITEM Content--->    
         <div class="card card-carousel">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/guru.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/admin.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Cara pengoperasian website yogya learning dengan admin.</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16">Admin satu
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">302</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
         <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/how.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Cara mengatasi stress dalam pekerjaan</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16">Putri ADM
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">444</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
           <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/mscale.gif" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Cara pemakaian M-Scale</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16">Indah ADM
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">231</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
          <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/terima.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Cara menyapa pelanggan</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16">Andri Staf toko
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">421</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
           <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/user.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Belajar memahami sistem alur kerja warehouse.</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16">Candra Staff WMS
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">121</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
          <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/guru.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Learn how to live your fullest life.</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16"> Dr. Strange
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">204</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a>
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
        Previous
        Next
        <!---End Card--->
        <!---Slide Start Card--->
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide carouselss" data-bs-ride="carousel">
           <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/guru.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Learn how to live your fullest life.</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="15">Dr. Strange Supply Chain
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">204</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
      <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/admin.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Cara pengoperasian website yogya learning dengan admin.</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16">Admin satu
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">302</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a>
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
         <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/how.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Cara mengatasi stress dalam pekerjaan</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16">Putri ADM
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">444</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
           <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/mscale.gif" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Cara pemakaian M-Scale</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16">Indah ADM
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">231</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
          <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/terima.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Cara menyapa pelanggan</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16">Andri Staf toko
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">421</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
           <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/user.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Belajar memahami sistem alur kerja warehouse.</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16">Candra Staff WMS
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">121</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
          <!--START ITEM Content--->
         <div class="card card-carousel">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/guru.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <b><p>Learn how to live your fullest life.</p></b>
            <p>
            <img>assets/icon/guru.svg" width="15" height="16"> Dr. Strange
            <br>
            <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> <img>assets/icon/star-fill.svg" width="16" height="16"> 
          <br>
                <img>assets/icon/person.svg" width="16" height="16">204</p>
            <a href="#">Start Courses</a> 
        <!--END ITEM Content--->
        Previous
        Next
        <!---End Card--->
```

I was expecting when i click next button it will move the slide for each slide

Comment: Please reformat your code. Currently it is nearly unreadable and syntactically incorrect.

Comment: In most of your `img` tag,  you are missing `src="<?php echo base_url() ?`. Update the code here if still you are facing the issue.